# Looking for the official ATA-4 specification/RFC

Tags: rfc, specifications, ata

I'm looking for one of the following:
- ATA-4 Specification
- A wrapper for the ATA-4 specification written in Real Mode Assembly (MASM/TURBO ASM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ata-atapi.com/hist.html#T18

> ATA/ATAPI-4 is ANSI document number INCITS 317-1998.

(see also http://t13.incits.org/t13sd4.htm)

If you want to read the actual ANSI standard you have to purchase it. Not sure who is the best source but I did find [one source online](http://www.techstreet.com/standards/INCITS/317_1998?product_id=56120).

as far as assembly libraries go... that sounds like a tough call, I found [something](http://www.singlix.com/trdos/ataid.html) but no idea as to its viability/correctness/licensing.

Comment: Looking good.  Now if you had the ASM wrapper as well it might have meant a little green tick...;-)

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah, Google also gave me the "something"...Good enough for me.  Thanks anyway.